# Using filter() inside the filter() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to filter the data, this is my data:

```
var data = {
    CustomerInfo: [{ id : 3, name: "c" }],
    detail: {company: "Google"},
    location: {country: "Italy"},
    CustomerInfo2: [{ id : 4, name: "d" }]
};
```

and I want to print each name that is not the object format (`data[x][x] !== 'object'`). for example, print just the "**company**" and "**country**".
here is my code:

```
var dataFiltered = Object.keys(data).filter(function(parent){

    return Object.keys(data[parent]).filter(function(child){
      return typeof data[parent][child] !== 'object';
    });

}).reduce(function(prev, child) {
  console.log(prev + " >>> " + data[child]);
});
```

I am kind of messed up with the filter inside the filter.

at the end I want this result:

```
company >>> Google
country >>> Italy
```

Comment: The `filter` callback is expected to return a boolean. Not an array like your inner `filter`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just test `Array.isArray`?

Comment: @Bergi no because you can also access properties of objects with `foo[bar]`

Comment: @Kristianmitk You can do that on strings as well, so no difference there. I'm not sure what your actual goal is, the distinction in your example would work if `Array.isArray` just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```js
var data = {
    CustomerInfo: [{ id : 3, name: "c" }],
    detail: {company: "Google"},
    location: {country: "Italy"},
    CustomerInfo2: [{ id : 4, name: "d" }]
};

let result = Object.keys(data).reduce((a, b) => {
    if(typeof data[b] == 'object'){
        for(let element of Object.keys(data[b])){
            if(typeof data[b][element] != 'object'){
                a.push(data[b][element]);
                console.log(element, '>>>', data[b][element]);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
},[]);

console.log(result)
```